# QSqlQuery not positioned on a valid record

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

I'm trying select a field of my date base, the code is:

```
if (db.db().isOpen())
{
  qDebug() << "OK";
  QSqlQuery query("SELECT state FROM jobs WHERE jobId = '553'", db.db());
  qDebug() << query.value(0).toString();
}
else
  qDebug() << "No ok";
```

The query is correct because when I do  `qDebug() << query.size;`, it  returns `1`.

but with `qDebug() << query.value(0).toString();`, it returns:

```
OK 
QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record
""
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You should call `query.first()` before you can access returned data. additionally if your query returns more than one row, you should iterate via `query.next()`.

Comment: im doing these two things, but still getting the same issue. whats the deal?

Comment: An example (and useful details) you'll find on the [Qt's QSqlQuery documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#details).

Comment: Just as a call out, you do not need to call first() before calling next(), as the latter will position on the first record if necessary. @Igdorman you are probably passing an incorrect index to value(), presumably because you called record() before the query was active (e.g. before calling exec()).