# How to get the count of rows

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qt5, rowcount

I want to get the count of rows from last query.
I have used `size()` and `numRowsAffected()` functions, but none of them work.

I have written the following code:

```
int counter = 0;
QStringList TableHeader;
QSqlQuery qry;
qry.prepare("SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users) AS count FROM users");
qry.exec();

qDebug() << qry.value("count").toString(); // <<-- print the count of rows

ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(10);
ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(3);
TableHeader << "Username" << "Password" << "Age";
ui->tableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(TableHeader);
while (qry.next()) {
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(counter, 0, new QTableWidgetItem(qry.value("username").toString()));
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(counter, 1, new QTableWidgetItem(qry.value("password").toString()));
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(counter, 2, new QTableWidgetItem(qry.value("age").toString()));
    ui->tableWidget->item(counter, 0)->setData(Qt::UserRole, qry.value("id").toString());
    counter++;
}
```

But unfortunately this does not work fine and gives me an error `QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record`.

**I want to get the count of rows whether by using a query or function.**

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000123/qsqlquery-not-positioned-on-a-valid-record

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: Thanks, but the answer of the question that in the link not clear,  I need an example in order to understand the solution.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: Quote from the answer which in the link: `additionally if your query returns more than one row, you should iterate via query.next().`, as you seen in my previous code, I have used `qry.next()`. For this reason, I want an example to clear the mystery.

Comment: Did you call qry.first(), first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`qry.size()` is not supported with SQLite. `QSqlQuery::last ()` retrieves the last record in the result, if available, and positions the query on the retrieved record. After calling `last()` you can retrieve index of the last record and position the query before the first record using `first()` and `previous()` :

```
int numberOfRows = 0;
if(qry.last())
{
    numberOfRows =  qry.at() + 1;
    qry.first();
    qry.previous(); 
}
```

Comment: I thank you for your answer. but why you use  `qry.at() + 1` **plus one**, also why you use `qry.previous() `, note that you use `qry.first();`.

Comment: @LionKing `QSqlQuery::at` returns the index of the row starting from zero. So the first row has an index of `0` and the last one has an index of `n-1`. So plusing one is the number of the rows. `qry.previous()` is called to position the query before the first row. This is the exact state when you run query. If you don't like it you can simply emit it.